# Customer Admin Shopping Cart only displays 20 items

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, shopping-cart, ce-1.9.2.4

I'm running Magento 1.9.2.4 and when I go to view a customers shopping cart in admin, it only lists up to 20 items, even though the header bar of the cart says 30 items (for example).

Can someone point me to the place in the application where I can modify this to make sure all cart line items are displayed?